# Can I upgrade the software on Cointerra TerraMiner IV?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware, miner-configuration, mining-software, bitcoin-xt

I got in to bitcoin mining about a year ago by purchasing a used Cointerra TerraMiner IV. The price of bitcoin was higher than the electricity cost to run the machine. I don't know a lot about the internals of the machine, but I know it's 4 GoldStrike I 28nm ASIC boards (2 per board) controlled by an embedded linux beaglebone board. With the current news about the Bitcoin/XT split, I'm wondering if it's possible to upgrade the mining software to support XT.

I'm not too familiar with ASIC boards—does "application-specific" exclude Bitcoin XT in this case?

My background: Computer Science/Software Engineering/Internet Security Research

Answer (score 1):

The miner does not need a software upgrade to mine with Bitcoin XT.  The pool or whichever mining solution you choose would need to connect to a Bitcoin XT node rather than a Bitcoin core node.